# COM interop returns ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop, csom

I have a C++ non-managed program calling into a C# DLL using COM interop to access a sharepoint server using SharePoint CSOM.

- Calling from C++ returns hr == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.
- Calling the same DLL function from a C# test program works successfully.

Here is the C# function I am calling...

```
public class SharePointUpload : ISharePointUpload
{
    public void Testing()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Testing4");

        using (var context = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://mysharepointsite.com/sites/mysite"))
        {
           MessageBox.Show("3");
        }
    }
}
```

... and the calling code in C++ is...

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
CComPtr <ISharePointUpload>     pISharePointUpload;
HRESULT hr = pISharePointUpload.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(SharePointUpload));
if (hr == S_OK) {
    hr = pISharePointUpload->Testing();
    // returns hr == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
}
CoUninitialize();
```

As noted, calling Testing() returns hr == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, and none of the MessageBoxes are shown.  If I remove the "using (var context..." line, then I can call the Testing() function, and I see the message boxes.

I can still call other functions in the C# DLL.  I also have a C# test program that calls the same DLL, and that works fine - I can connect to the sharepoint server and upload files.

I'm thinking maybe I need to add something to my C++ application.  I have used the NuGet Console to "Install-Package Microsoft.SharepointOnline.CSOM", and I can see that this has created a packages.config file in the solution with the package, but this did not help.

Comment: It's probably a deployment issue. The Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext misses something in the context of the C++ client to be instantiated properly. Have you called CoInitialize(Ex) in your C++ code? Otherwise use a tool such as Procmon from sysinternals filter by file access and you should see what files are missing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Thanks.  Procmon is getting me there - my program is looking for the SharePoint Client 16.1, to match the NuGet package, but the latest available download of the Sharepoint Online Client Components SDK is 16.0.  I can't find 16.1 anywhere.  Is it recommended for my install package to install the NuGet command line and package(s) on users' computers, or do I need to grab any relevant .dll files out of the package directory, and package them with my install?

Comment: Usually nugets are only for developpers. How it will all run elsewhere is entirely dependent on the nuget/technology involved. This is a pure Sharepoint client issue.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  That's what I thought, but it was odd that the Nuget package for CSOM is using a later version of Sharepoint client than is actually available.  I will take the necessary DLLs from the Nuget package, and wrap them into my own install script.  As for the C++ interop issue, I tried many variations, with different versions of Sharepoint clients, and older CSOM Nuget packages, and could not get anything to work.  I've re-architected my software to use an independent C# program for the Sharepoint interface, and run this program in the background.  All good now, thanks.